# IndexOutofRangeException while using WriteLine in nested Parallel.For loops

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect-sdk

I am trying to write kinect depth data to a text file using nested Parallel.For loops with the following code. However, it gives `IndexOutofRangeException`.

The code works perfect if using simple for loops but it hangs the UI since the depth format is set to `640x480` causing the loops to write `307200 lines` in the text file at `30fps`.

Therefore, I switched to Parallel. For scheme. If I omit the writeLine command from the nested loops, the code works fine, which indicates that the `IndexOutofRangeException` is arising at the writeline command. I do not know how to troubleshoot this. Please advise.

Any better workarounds to avoid UI freezing?

Thanks.

```
using (DepthImageFrame depthImageframe = d.OpenDepthImageFrame())
            {
                if (depthImageframe == null)
                    return;
                depthImageframe.CopyPixelDataTo(depthPixelData);

                swDepth = new StreamWriter(@"E:\depthData.txt", false);
                int i = 0;

                Parallel.For(0, depthImageframe.Width, delegate(int x)
                {
                    Parallel.For(0, depthImageframe.Height, delegate(int y)
                    {
                        p[i] = sensor.MapDepthToSkeletonPoint(depthImageframe.Format,
                                x, y, depthPixelData[x + depthImageframe.Width * y]);
                        swDepth.WriteLine(i + "," + p[k].X + "," + p[k].Y + "," + p[k].Z);
                        i++;
                    });
                });            

                swDepth.Close();

            }
        }
```

Comment: Well then, where is the variable k assigned? Or should it be 'i' instead? And for performance, you should use string.Format instead of +

Comment: Probably `k` is leftover from some old code, so replace `p[k]` with `p[i]`.

Comment: i guess one parallel loop is enough, doing 300000 parallel tasks does not really increase the performance

Comment: yeah "k" was a typo, its actually "i".

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is not IndexOutofRange.  You see IndexOutofRangeException only because of some internal implementation of StreamWriter. The main problem is that you are using swDepth.WriteLine from multiple threads. That explains why your code works with normal fors, but fails with parallel fors.

Check link 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx. It says that only static members of StreamWriter are thread safe.

To fix this just replace

```
swDepth.WriteLine(i + "," + p[k].X + "," + p[k].Y + "," + p[k].Z);
```

with

```
lock(someSyncObject)
    swDepth.WriteLine(i + "," + p[k].X + "," + p[k].Y + "," + p[k].Z);
```

Also make sure that sensor.MapDepthToSkeletonPoint can work in multiple threads.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion as the following. This time no error, but the UI freezes up. I terminated the program and opened the depthData.txt. There were 188000 entries written till now. This means the loop had not finished when I terminated the program. This doesnt seem a good way to write all the values of p in the text file without freezing the UI.  
object someSyncObject = new object();
 lock (someSyncObject)
                            swDepth.WriteLine(i + "," + p[i].X + "," + p[i].Y + "," + p[i].Z);

                        i++;

Comment: In this case, you have to move this work to different (non-UI) thread. You can do this by using Task class. It is quite simple - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051.aspx. This will run your method in a background thread from a threadpool. If you will run this code in non-UI thread, you should also verify that it is worth using Parallel.For. In some cases simple for is faster than parallel.for beacuse of some overhead and sychronization requirements

Comment: When I omit the WriteLine command, the code works fine without causing the UI to freeze however, adding the WriteLine command makes the UI freeze.

Comment: Ok, so the nested for loop code goes into computeSkeletonPoints(DepthImageFrame depthImageframe) and I call it using:
var t1 =  Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => computeSkeletonPoints(depthImageframe));

however, it gives the following error:
A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread.

Comment: Getting the following errors:
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread.

Comment: I have caught the IO exception in a message box and it says "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".

Comment: I don´t fully understand what you have put into Task, but you should put there all your code from your question (starting with "using (DepthImageFrame ..."). Not only MapDepthToSkeletonPoint and WriteLine